# JSONB Postgres 9.4

Tags: search, indexing, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a jsonb storing my order product:

```
CREATE TABLE configuration (
  documentid text PRIMARY KEY
, data jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

Records:

```
(1, [{"itemid": "PROD001", "qty": 10}, {"itemid": "PROD002", "qty": 20}]),
(2, [{"itemid": "PROD001", "qty": 5}, {"itemid": "PROD003", "qty": 6}, {"itemid": "PROD004", "qty": 7}]),
(2, [{"itemid": "PROD002", "qty": 8}])
```

I already index data using GIN.

How do I:

1. Select all sales that has PROD001
2. Select all sales that has itemid LIKE P%1
3. Select all sales that has qty > 10
4. get each product total qty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Postgres documentation regarding JSON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) functionality is really clear and worth your attention. As for the use cases you provided, answers may be the following:

```
-- Answer 1
SELECT sales_item 
FROM configuration,jsonb_array_elements(data) AS sales_item
WHERE sales_item->>'itemid' = 'PROD001'; --  "->>" returns TEXT value
-- Answer 2
SELECT sales_item FROM configuration,jsonb_array_elements(data) AS sales_item
WHERE sales_item->>'itemid' LIKE 'P%1'; -- just use LIKE
-- Answer 3
SELECT sales_item FROM configuration,jsonb_array_elements(data) AS sales_item
WHERE (sales_item->>'qty')::INTEGER > 10; -- convert TEXT to INTEGER
```

For last example you just need to use [Postgres Window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
-- Answer 4 
SELECT DISTINCT documentid,sum((sales_item->>'qty')::INTEGER) 
OVER (PARTITION BY documentid)
FROM configuration,jsonb_array_elements(data) as sales_item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples 1,3 with [JsQuery extension](https://github.com/postgrespro/jsquery)

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data) as elem FROM configuration
    WHERE data @@ '#.itemid = "PROD001"') q
    WHERE q.elem @@ 'itemid = "PROD001"'

SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data) as elem FROM configuration
    WHERE data @@ '#.qty > 10') q
    WHERE q.elem @@ 'qty > 10'
```

Inner query WHERE clause filters rows doesn't have any array element that matches requirements. Than jsonb_array_elements func. is applied only for needed rows of "configuration" table.